# What does a raw tcp conversation look like, down to the nitial syn/ack requests

Tags: networking, tcp, packet

I would be interested in learning more about TCP, and possibly implementing it myself, but I can not seem to find any info on what a raw tcp conversation including the syn/synack/ack packets.

I want something like this, but the actual, raw data the two systems are sending and receiving

```
Client: syn
server: synack
client: ack
client: GET / HTTP/1.1
server: <h1>Website</h1>
```

Comment: TCP is a standard, which is described in a number of RFCs published by IETF. You can find an overview in [rfc7414](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7414). TCP header format and how to process SYN/SYNACK packets can be found in rfc793 (link in sec 2 of rfc7414).

Comment: you could try for example [this link](https://www.computer-networking.info/2nd/html/protocols/tcp.html) for an overview.

Comment: @Effie Thanks for the links, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I have read through the two linked docs and and rfc793, but I could not find much or any info on the raw SYN/SYNACK/ACK packets and what would come after them.

Comment: @MatthiasLee You're mixing details from different protocol layers. The SYN/SYN+ACK/ACK sequence belongs to TCP in the transport layer. The `GET` belongs to HTTP in the application layer. HTTP doesn't see the internals of TCP and TCP doesn't care what payload it transports. Do you want to see how TCP works internally (then read the RFC from Effie's comment) or do you want to know how it is used?

Comment: @Zac67 Oh, ok. I read the rfcs, but I do not know how I can actually implement this in ruby. I assume there is some sort of raw socket but Im not sure.

Comment: If there's a TCP/IP stack all you've got to do is the HTTP part. Use a TCP socket for that. Done.

Comment: @Zac67 Yeah, I know how to do that. My goal is to implement the protocol myself as to use IP spoofing for a project I have

Comment: Then you should implement TCP and HTTP functionality seperately.

Comment: @Zac67 Ok, but how am I supposed to implement TCP

Comment: this is OS dependant. Linux has an interface, called "raw sockets" that allows you to accept packets from layers 3 or 2 of the stack. Then you implement TCP on top of a raw socket. Usually, this works in C and I don't know if ruby can give you access to one of those. I would however advise not to do this, as implementing TCP that satisfies basic requirements of internet hosts and is interoperable by other TCPs is already extremely comlicated. If the goal is IP spoofing I would try to look for a way to post-process packets, created by OS TCP impl.

Comment: this is also OS dependant. On Linux I would start looking into IP tables. But I am not entirely familiar with such tools, there might be better ones.

Comment: [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4808760/user786) is trying to implement TCP. You can check how he struggles.